# How to fetch Cover Art for MEDIA (MediaStore.Audio.Media) in android (API 19)

Tags: java, android, audio, uri, albumart

So i'm trying to build a very simple music player (I started working with android just a few days ago). Till now I wrote the code to retrieve songs informations. However I'm not able to retrieve the album art for every single media.
I know there is a column ALBUM_ART in MediaStore.Audio.Album (I tried to retrieve the Album art for each album and it worked), but I want to assign the album art to each song and I don't know how to do it.
Surfing the net I found this kind of code:

```
Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, all I get is `null`. Can someone explain me how to retrieve the album art for each song?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] columns = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                   android.provider. MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART };
            int album_column_index=0;
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                    null, null);
    
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    
                    
                    arrAlbumNAme.add( cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));
                    album_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
                    //cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    albumID = cursor.getInt(album_column_index);
                    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumID);
                    arrAlbumArt.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)));
    
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }


Inside adapter
holder.image_icon.setImageUri(arrAlbumArt.get(position));
```